# CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE wipes values at indices of >63 in local arrays

Tags: opencl

I've run into a weird bug in a kernel. I reproduced the bug with a simple kernel:

```
//data is initialized as {0, 0, 0}
//x has size 128 and is not initialized to anything
__kernel void testBarrier(__global int *data, __local uint* x) {
    x[0] = 1;
    x[63] = 1;
    x[64] = 1;

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    data[0] = x[0];
    data[1] = x[63];
    data[2] = x[64];
}
```

I then print off data on the host side and I see

```
1, 1, 0
```

If I comment out "barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);", then I see

```
1, 1, 1
```

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Edit: The number of work items and work group size doesn't seem to matter. I even tried a single work item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that commenting out the barrier gives the possibility to the compiler to optimize the code that way:

```
data[0] = 1;
data[1] = 1;
data[2] = 1;
```

Which is not possible with the barrier function since with the flag:

> CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE - The barrier function will either flush any
>   variables stored in local memory or queue a memory fence to ensure
>   correct ordering of memory operations to local memory.

Obviously, you shouldn't see any difference in the result, but with that possible optimization in mind I'd start by investigate the size of x. Specifically I'd check the `clSetKernelArg` call for x making sure it is at least

```
sizeof(cl_uint) * 65;
```

Do you use an AMD GPU? Because typically reads and write out of bounds are completely transparent to the developer on that platform (See question 55 in that [FAQ](http://community.topcoder.com/amdapp/faq-2/)).
BTW you can verify the optimization hypothesis by passing the option '-cl-opt-disable' when calling clBuildProgram.

Comment: What does it mean to flush variables in local memory? Also, I'll check the size of *x* and trying disabling optimizations. I am using an AMD GPU, and I did notice that it doesn't mind out of bounds writes, but thanks for that link. Good to know for sure. I'll try all this out after work today and see what happens.

Comment: It means to restore the value from the register to the local memory.

Comment: You were right about the size of x. It was too small. It's odd that the  CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE had that effect, but I also don't know the details of the hardware.